# What is the meaning of `struct X typedef` vs. `typedef struct X`?

Tags: c++, c, struct, visual-studio-2010

I have the following (working) code in an existing code base, used in include file that is shared between C and C++, compiling on MSVC (2010) and Windows DDK:

```
struct X {
    USHORT x;
} typedef X, *PX;
```

And:

```
enum MY_ENUM {
    enum_item_1,
    enum_item_2 
} typedef MY_ENUM;
```

As far as I know, correct definition should look like this:

```
typedef struct {
    USHORT x;
} X, *PX;
```

Is there any purpose for having the form below? Am I missing something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

Comment: Plenty of great answers here :)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The fact that both `typedef <type> <alias>` and `<type> typedef <alias>` are valid simply comes from the language grammar definition.

`typedef` is classified as a *storage-class specfifier* (just like `static`, `auto`), and the type itself is known as the *type-specifier*.  From the syntax definitions in section 6.7 of the standard, you'll see that these are free to be interchanged:

```
declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list ;

declaration-specifiers:
    storage-class-specifier declaration-specifiers
    type-specifier declaration-specifiers
    type-qualifier declaration-specifiers
    function-specifier declaration-specifiers

init-declarator-list:
    init-declarator
    init-declarator-list , init-declarator

init-declarator:
    declarator
    declarator = initializer
```

(Note, of course, that this is equally true for structs and for non-structs, meaning that `double typedef trouble;` is also valid.)

Answer (score 18):

As others said, `typedef` is a storage-class specifier and as with other storage-class specifiers you are also allowed to put the specifier between the type and the declarator.

While this is valid and it is also a form that should be avoided as C marked it as an obsolescent feature:

> (C11, 6.11.5p1) "The placement of a storage-class specifier other than at the beginning of the declaration specifiers in a declaration is an obsolescent feature."

Answer (score 6):

Both have the same meaning. Both of these two forms are valid:

```
typedef <existing_type> <new_type>
<existing_type> typedef <new_type>
```

You can `typedef` the above struct in either ways:

```
struct X {
    USHORT x;
}typedef X, *PX;     // <existing_type> typedef <new_type>
```

or

```
typedef struct {
    USHORT x;
} X, *PX;            // typedef <existing_type> <new_type>
```

Comment: Shouldn't it always be "typedef <Type> <Alias>"? Is this a special extension for structs?

Comment: @Itaypk Not just structs, as your can see from your `enum` example.

Comment: The position of `typedef` is largely irrelevant, you can also have `int typedef i;`. This is no special extension for structs. (Oli Charlesworth's answer covers that part.)

Answer (score 5):

You really are allowed to put all the declaration specifiers in any order you want!  The positions of any `*` pointers and the actual declarator (the variable or new type name) matter, but all that `typedef` `int` `unsigned` `const` `static` etc. stuff can be in any order.

If you look at the official grammar of C, it just says:

```
declaration:
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list ;
```

The `declaration-specifiers` are all the storage class specifiers (`typedef`, `extern`, etc.), type specifiers (the actual type, like `int` or `struct X`), type qualifiers (`const` and `volatile`), and a few other less common ones.  Their order is not important.  The second part is the `init-declarator-list`, and it's the variable or new type name (in the case of a typedef), any `*` characters, the initialization of the variable (`int x = 3`), and more.  The order of things in the declarator part is important, but not the order in the declaration specifiers.

Answer (score 5):

*Disclaimer: This is not a technical but a practical answer. Refer to the other answers for technical matters. This answer reads opinionated and subjective but please bear with me while I try to explain the bigger picture.*

`struct` is a strange beast because the stuff you put between the closing bracket `}` and the semicolon `;` refers to the content inside or before those brackets. I know why that is, and grammatically it does make sense, but personally I find it very counter-intuitive as curly brackets usually mean scope:

**Counter-intuitive examples:**

```
// declares a variable named `foo` of unnamed struct type.
struct {
    int x, y;
} foo;

foo.x = 1;


// declares a type named `Foo` of unnamed struct type
struct {
    int x, y;
} typedef Foo;

Foo foo2;
foo2.x = 2;


// declares a type named `Baz` of the struct named `Bar`
struct Bar {
    int x, y;
} typedef Baz;

// note the 'struct' keyword to actually use the type 'Bar'
struct Bar bar;
bar.x = 3;
Baz baz;
baz.x = 4;
```

There are so many subtle things that can go wrong with the dense syntax of `struct`s and `typedef`s if used like this. As shown below it is very easy to declare a variable instead of a type by accident. The compiler is only of limited help because almost all combinations are grammatically correct. They just don't necessarily mean what you try to express. It is a [pit of despair](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/08/14/c-and-the-pit-of-despair.aspx).

**Wrong examples:**

```
// mixed up variable and type declaration
struct foo {
    int x, y;
} Foo;

// declares a type 'foo' instead of a variable
typedef struct Foo {
    int x, y;
} foo;

// useless typedef but compiles fine
typedef struct Foo {
    int x, y;
};

// compiler error
typedef Foo struct {
    int x, y;
};
```

For reasons of readability and maintenance I prefer to declare everything separately and never put anything behind the closing curly bracket. The cost of additional lines of code are easily outweighed by intuitive syntax. I argue that this approach [makes it easy to do the right things and annoying to do the wrong things](http://blog.codinghorror.com/falling-into-the-pit-of-success/).

**Intuitive examples:**

```
// declares a struct named 'TVector2'
struct TVector2 {
    float x, y;
};

// declares a type named 'Vector2' to get rid of the 'struct' keyword
// note that I really never use 'TVector2' afterwards
typedef struct TVector2 Vector2;

Vector2 v, w;
v.x = 0;
v.y = 1;
```